# XSD - how to remove some generated excess classes from JAXB processing?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

It's a while that I had to touch XMLand Schema files.
I have created an XSD schema from some sample payload and then used maven-jaxp to generate Java classes from that. 
The XML contains lists of elements in the form of

```
<Root>
   <Subs>
      <Sub />
      <Sub />
      [...]
   </Subs>
</Root>
```

and the derived xsd defines a RootType, a SubsType and a SubType for this example. I want to implement "Subs" as an ArrayList instead of a generated class, how do I change the XSD for this?

Cheers,
Kai

Comment: Maybe you can share the relevant part of your XSD?

Comment: <xs:complexType name="RootType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="SubType" name="Subs"/>
        </xs:sequence>

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments. Use the 'edit' button and put it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution is to add an extension to the jaxb2-maven-plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <packageName>my.model</packageName>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-no-header</argument>
                    <argument>-Xxew</argument>
                    <argument>-Xxew:instantiate lazy</argument>
                   </arguments>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.github.jaxb-xew-plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-xew-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.10</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```